# Error using Backups in Ubuntu 18.10 (it was Deja Dup)

Tags: backup, 18.10, deja-dup

*My final goal is to have a full backup of the system (like time-machine) and use it to reinstall it in case of disaster.
The intermediate goal is to backup all the working areas more times over the day.*

Well, I followed all your suggestions: 
    removed deja-dup
    installed Backups using apt-get
    didn't backup the root (not yet applied the suggested patches to incorporate /)

but the result is always the same. it looks as there is some corrupted data: Note the the final message is always the same!!!!

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1555, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1541, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1393, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1511, in do_backup
    full_backup(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 572, in full_backup
    globals.backend)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 454, in write_multivol
    (tdp, dest_filename, vol_num)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 146, in schedule_task
    return self.__run_synchronously(fn, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 172, in __run_synchronously
    ret = fn(*params)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 453, in <lambda>
    vol_num: put(tdp, dest_filename, vol_num),
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 342, in put
    backend.put(tdp, dest_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 395, in inner_retry
    % (n, e.__class__.__name__, util.uexc(e)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/util.py", line 79, in uexc
    return ufn(unicode(e).encode('utf-8'))
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The configuration is now:

```
Folder to save: /etc /dev /run /bi /sbin /snap /sys /proc /opt /media /root /lib64 /lib /srv /var /usr /mnt
Folders to ignore: Trash, /backup, /git, /neo4j, /sys_backup /home
Storage location: Local folder - /sys_backup
```

Comment: Why are you running a snap version of deja-dup when `Backups` (same thing) is included in 18.xx? Also, you wouldn't use deja-dup to backup /.

Comment: Well, I uninstalled DejaDup and trried to search for Backup, but nothing happened.
I did sudo apt-get install Backup put nothing was found.

The only I found to install is 'command 'backup' from deb openafs-client`
`

So, the answer at your question is: I didn't find any Backup, and decided to install DejaDup.

Any idea how to retrieve and install the original one?

The only I found is `command 'backup' from deb openafs-client`

Comment: Three versions of deja-dup can be found in the Ubuntu Software store... snap, flatpack, and traditional .deb. You might also try and reinstall duplicity. Backups was never designed to backup the system-level folders that you're backing up. See my answer for info about Timeshift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uninstall the snap version of deja-dup, and install the non-snap version. Use deja-dup to backup **specific** folders in your home directory (not all of / or ~/).

```bsh
sudo snap remove deja-dup # remove the snap version
sudo apt-get update # update the software database
sudo apt-get install deja-dup # install deja-dup
```

---

Install `timeshift` and use it to backup system/OS files...

The closest thing to a Windows-like restore point is by using `Timeshift`. I use it to save snapshots to an external USB hard drive. Although it can, it's normally not used for backing up your /home directory, just system-level changes. Use `Backups` (Déjà Dup) for backing up /home files.

```
Timeshift is a system restore utility which takes snapshots
of the system at regular intervals. These snapshots can be restored
at a later date to undo system changes. Creates incremental snapshots
using rsync or BTRFS snapshots using BTRFS tools.
```

More information at https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

Add the PPA and install with:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install timeshift
```

Comment: I use the non-snap version of duplicity, and I get precisely the same error message :(

Comment: @DYZ Three versions of deja-dup can be found in the Ubuntu Software store... snap, flatpack, and traditional .deb. You might also try and reinstall duplicity. Backups was never designed to backup the system-level folders that you're backing up. See my answer for info about Timeshift.

Comment: I do not back up system-level folders, I backup my personal folders. You confused me with the OP.

Comment: @DYZ Gett'in old ya know :-) Does reinstalling duplicity help at all?

Comment: Not really, Now I am getting "Another duplicity instance is already running with this archive directory."

Comment: In `terminal`, see `dpkg -l *duplicity* | grep ii`, and `ps auxc | grep -i duplicity`.

Comment: No luck, getting the same original error about 'ascii' code.

Comment: @DYZ Please start a new question. Provide as much detail as you can, including what you've tried to do to fix it. Please include `snap list` and `dpkg -l *deja* | grep ii`. Thanks.

Comment: The advice to use the non-snap version (or non-flatpak, in my case) worked for me! After many hours of trying to get past timeouts, `FileNotUploadedError`s, and `Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com` with the flatpack version (v42.0), I tried the `deb` version (v40.7), and it worked. Thanks! I posted my experience here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259348/deja-dup-unable-to-find-the-server-at-www-googleapis-com-and-filenotuploaded/1259349

Comment: @joe Rather than starting a new question, with the same results, it would be better to just up vote this answer, as it solved your problem.

Comment: @heynnema This isn't actually the same error/problem - I only found it by chance after looking through about a dozen different askubuntu/launchpad threads. My question/answer should be much easier for people to find, because we all run a Google for the error message as a first impulse when debugging.

Comment: @joe It's the same solution. The problem is, we don't support Pop_OS at this site. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @heynnema, gotcha, although that's a different problem. I will get back to you (and update/move the post) on whether this is Pop-specific.

Comment: @heynnema I just saw your "It's the same solution" edit. That's not a reason for not creating another question. Lots of very *different* questions have the same solution: "Question: How to fix ___? Solution: Restart your computer." The stack exchange sites are for helping people find answers to their questions. Policies around valid/useful content should be arranged around that core principle. I'm not interested in further debate here, in case you disagree (not trying to be unfriendly, it's just not a good use of my time).

Answer (score 1):

Dejadup works fine for root. You just have to do it right.

[How do I open Deja Dup as root?](https://askubuntu.com/a/130702/6045)

I suggest you separate your system and user backups.

It would probably be helpful if the application detected this pattern and advised the user of this alternative method.

Comment: I didn't find `sudo deja-dup-preferences`

Any idea how/where to find it?

Comment: @PaoloDiPietro You can't find it because it's been removed. Great... Honestly, A backup that complex is better done using duplicity directly. Run it as root via a cron and make sure it preserves permissions/ownership.  Example, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/duplicity#Front-ends