# Backups program fails to backup. And the Backup Now button is grayed out

Tags: lubuntu, backup

I had been running the Backups program successfully in Lubuntu 18.04.3, in order to backup the Home folder to an external drive (which has plenty of space on it).

The Backups program worked successfully for several months. For the last 318 days now, though, the daily attempts of the Backups program to perform backups automatically have failed. And the Backup Now button is grayed out.
(Since then until now, I was too overwhelmed to get engaged on this web site to try to get help to fix the problem.)

I am a relative newbie - and almost always I use GUIs. I can perform Terminal commands **IF** they are provided together with complete and precise instructions.

Comment: You mention 18.04.3; meaning your system could be as much as a year behind on upgraded packages (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/ , an upgraded system will report itself as 18.04.5 which is current; the date on my link refers to ISO release; an installed system updates before then usually; ie. you haven't applied updates since 2020-Feb-12 potentially...) and issues maybe fixed if you just update (it could also be 18.04.3 was your install ISO, and not what your system is now).

Comment: Hi guiverc. Thank you, and sorry. It is Lubuntu 18.04.5. (I do install offered updates.)

Comment: I don't know the program you're referring to sorry, but I would probably run the program from terminal, so messages appear on screen (instead of needing to explore logs) and look for clues. From your description, that maybe difficult for you (as it's not something you're accustomed to doing).  I'd also explore permissions of the drive (`touch` or create files where you want to store your backups) to ensure nothing has changed 318 days ago. Is the *file-system* being used to store your backups to POSIX compliant? or a non-native *file-system*?

Comment: The program called Backups comes installed with Lubuntu 18.04. It is a combination of  Déjà Dup and Duplicity - and it is called 'Backups'.

Comment: I don't know the name of the file system I'm using. I am simply backing up to a WD Passport external hard drive.

Comment: I booted up a Lubuntu 18.04.5 *live* system and didn't see any backup program (outside of `rsync` & terminal tools common to all Ubuntu systems), nor see any with https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lubuntu-desktop (I suspect you've added it and it's not a default program).  I'm guessing your external WD drive is NTFS thus non-POSIX (unless you re-formatted it) so as I don't know the program, and it's a foreign *fs* I'd explore as per my prior comment.

Comment: My last comment probably won't help, as the exploration would likely have been unhelpful too (as really requires some IT/computer knowledge).  If you open the file manager (`pcmanfm`) and navigate directory where you save your backups, and try to create (`touch` is the command, but you can right-click and *Create New* and select "Empty File" which is the `touch` command). Does this provide any clues? (ie. error messages).  I prefer commands as the error messages are easier to see errors when they occur, a quick play with copy/paste & create-new (`touch`) both had errors visible & not visible

Comment: guiverc, thank you for being so perceptive, instructive and helpful. You are making this issue clearer to me, little by little. Yes, apparently I must have installed Deja Dup via System Tools/ Software.  After that, it has always been listed in Accessories under the name Backups, with a square, black icon (and not under the name Deja Dup).

Comment: Regarding the file type on the WD external HD that I use for backing up, I have waded into Terminal on my own by using the command sudo fdisk -l. The resulting o/p says that /dev/sdb1 is of type Microsoft basic data. Additionally I created a new empty file in the external drive, using pcmanfm, and I looked at its permissions - and found it stated that anyone can access, change or execute. By the way, I wouldn't have thought that the file system in  use on the external drive would be an issue, as previous to failing the backup program had been backing up successfully for several months.

Comment: If it's an issue in the program, as I know nothing about the program (nor exactly which program it is; `backup` is likely how it appears in menu but there are many - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) I can't advise. I'd expect log files provide your answer (or clue leading to answer), or I would run the program from command line so messages appear on screen. I'd also explore system logs (`dmesg`, `journalctl` looking for clues). I'd also explore /var/crash/ looking for anything there (if the program crashed; clues will be found there). I would check you have free space too

Comment: To figure out the program, look at the `Exec` line in the Desktop Entry. You may want to `grep -Ri backup /usr/share/applications` to figure out which file it is. Then `grep Exec /path/to/file.desktop` to get the `Exec` line. That will tell us the executable. You can use `which executable` to find its path. And you can use `dpkg -S /path/to/executable` to find out which package provides it.

Comment: FYI:  To tell the real name of a program (instead of the way it appears in menus as a number of different programs can appear the same way in menus; programmers assuming users won't load multiple programs that do the same thing..) you can usually look for an "About" option in the program. It'll also provide version details usually, which provides clues that allow us to test *theories* as to your program if it's name isn't specific enough.  FYI: Program install info is found in `/var/log/apt/` and may go back >318 days.. but that'd not be fun to explore

Comment: Thank you, guiverc and wxl.

Comment: Unfortunately, after your posts starting Jan 4 at 21:33 I got despondent, and shrank back. Your directions using commandline assume knowledge/familiarity that i don't have.  As I said, I need explicit directions when using commandline.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is why Linux never takes off with general public users.

Comment: Every time I hit return, I end the comment/post. Aye, aye, aye,

Comment: I'm surprised you don't recognize the name of the program: Deja Dup.

Comment: When I open Deja Dup (or Backups, as its listed in lubuntu) there is no "About".

Comment: When I do 'grep -Ri backup /usr/share/applications' (after replacing 'usr' with my username, then the return is "No such file or directory'.

Comment: `/usr/` is a special Linux directory, and is not related to "user" files in Linix (they are in /home/). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview refers to "/usr" as "*/usr contains the majority of user utilities and applications, and partly replicates the root directory structure, containing for instance, among others, /usr/bin/ and /usr/lib*"  I'm aware of *Deja Dup* but having never used it, I can't offer any advice sorry.

Comment: OK. Stumbling along here (sorry, and thanks again), I get

Comment: After I do $ grep -Ri DejaDup /usr/share/applications, then the return is
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.DejaDup.desktop:Icon=org.gnome.DejaDup

Comment: No. after $ grep Exec /path/to/DejaDup.desktop, the return is
grep: /path/to/DejaDup.desktop: No such file or directory

Comment: Lubuntu links can be found at https://lubuntu.me/links/ which offer alternatives to this site. IRC allows real-time chat, and also long comment trails tend to scare off people at this site (they'll get moved to SE Chat, which those of using Ubuntu SSO [*single sign on*} to access this site cannot access, as it requires a login to Stack Exchange). Lubuntu being an official flavor too, means you can use Ubuntu sites (Deja Dup being a Ubuntu program, I'd expect faster/better results in #ubuntu for example than #lubuntu)  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList

Comment: try https://askubuntu.com/questions/103397/deja-dups-back-up-now-button-is-not-highlighted

Answer (score 3):

My thanks to guiverc for the helpful comments and links, especially yesterday.
Accordingly, yesterday I read within [Deja Dup`s "Back Up Now" button is not highlighted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103397/deja-dups-back-up-now-button-is-not-highlighted)
how I could un-gray the 'Back Up Now' button.

Specifically, yesterday I killed a process id (that is, a pid) for the backup program DejaDup. It was the pid of DejaDup that ended in ' --backup --auto '. After rebooting the computer I found that the 'Back Up Now' button was un-grayed. Then, I clicked the 'Back Up Now' button, and DejaDup started creating a fresh backup, and the reason it provided was "in order to avoid corruption" of the backup. However, after about 4 hours the backup attempt failed, and then the 'Back Up Now' button was grayed out again.
Today I used the command line 'killall deja-dup', and once more the 'Back Up Now' button is ungrayed.

Via the website for DejaDup, wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup , I have filed a support request with the Gnome Infrastructure Team (at GitLab). Whereas DejaDup was updated on 13th January 2021 (according to the Software utility in lUbuntu 18.04.5), and whereas the aforementioned website for DejaDup was last updated on 25th August 2020, nevertheless this problem of grayed-out 'Back Up Now' button (and lack of a progress bar, by the way) is clearly over 8 years old by now.

Comment: In filing upstream (Deja Dup), you may not get much response as you're using an old version (older versions issues need to be tested & confirmed on the latest; currently in Ubuntu world that's *hirsute* 42.6 compared to your 37.1-2;  (fyi: I'm on Lubuntu *hirsute*).  Ubuntu only back-ports security fixes to older releases, not newer versions of software (unless it's more work to back-port security fixes only which is rare!).   But THANK YOU for filing upstream, someone on a later release may test, confirm it & that's how attention is gained & fixes get done, so again **thank you**.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 18.04 by default starts the Backup Monitor task which can cause the Backup Now button to be grayed out.

To disable the Backup Monitor task,

1. Start Lubuntu and log in
2. From the menu, select Preferences / Default Applications for LXSession
3. Click Autostart at the left
4. In the box at the bottom labeled Known Applications locate the item labeled Backup Monitor and untick its box

[image]

1. Restart the computer, then log back in
2. Plug your freshly prepared external backup media, formatted to ext4 and with a proper data partition created, into your system. Ensure that it is writeable by your user; use pcmanfm to create a dummy text file on it, then delete the dummy text fil.
3. Start Deja-Dup, aka Backups.
4. Configure Folders To Save and Folders to Ignore to meet your needs
5. Select Storage Location and point to your external backup media
6. Click Backup Now. A full backup will start.

Report back with details if any issues are encountered.